# Different dimensions when using numpy dot

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m
import numdifftools as nd

def g(x):
    return np.array(x[1]*m.exp(x[0]-1)+((x[1]**2)/3)-x[0]-2*x[1])

def Newton(f):
    Hess_f = nd.Hessian(f)
    Jac_f = nd.Jacobian(f)
    x0 = np.array([0,0])
    print(x0,len(x0),"info about x0")
    Hm = np.matrix(Hess_f(x0))
    Hi = np.linalg.inv(Hm)
    t = Jac_f(x0).dot(Hi)
    print(t, len(t),"info about t")
    x1 = x0 - t
    print(x1, len(x1),"info about x1")
    while np.linalg.norm(x1-x0) > 0.05:
        x0 = x1
        Hm = np.matrix(Hess_f(x0))
        Hi = np.linalg.inv(Hm)
        t = Jac_f(x0).dot(Hi)
        x1 = x0 - t
    print(x1)
    return(x1)

Newton(g)
```

As you can see, i got this print lines for seeing the lengths of the x0,x1 and t variables. The problem is with t and x1: the program shows they have length 1 (but when printed, they show 2 values in an array). Why is this?
the 0.05 in there is the error criteria for stopping the algorithm.

Comment: What is the shape of the array?  (Check, for example, `t.shape`.)  A numpy array with shape (1, 2) has  length 1.

Comment: It has shape (1,2). Still, it has 2 different values. Is there any way to retrieve both values separately?

Comment: You can index the array like any other numpy array.  The values are `t[0,0]` and `t[0,1]`.

Comment: You may also want to look into `x.size`: the total number of elements, `x.size == np.prod(x.shape)`

Comment: When working with numpy arrays, `shape` and `dtype` are the two most important attributes.  Length and size are secondary.

Comment: Keep in mi d that `np.matrix` creates a 2d array subclass.  It can useful but we often discourage its use.

Comment: The shape of `np.matrix(np.array([0,0]))` is (1,2).  `np.matrix` always returns a 2d array.  `len(...)`, more useful with lists than arrays, is 1, the first dimension.  If used in a `dot` that the other array should have a (2,n) shape.